# How to filter object within an array that matches search object in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, object

I am trying to filter and remove objects that are inside of my array however more objects are getting removed than I am hoping to target

```
const people = [
  {name: 'Adam', age: 30, country: 'USA'},
  {name: 'Carl', age: 30, country: 'UK'},
  {name: 'Bob', age: 40, country: 'China'},
 ];

const results = people.filter(element => {
  // ️ using AND (&&) operator
  return element.age !== 30 && element.name !== 'Carl';
});

console.log(results);
```

outputs:

```
[ { name: 'Bob', age: 40, country: 'China' } ]
```

I am hoping to only remove the object where Carl is found

My desired output would be

```
[ { name: 'Adam', age: 30, country: 'USA' }, { name: 'Bob', age: 40, country: 'China' } ]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to update the filter condition if you need to remove only 30yo Carls

```
return !(element.age === 30 && element.name === 'Carl');
```

which is equal to

```
return element.age !== 30 || element.name !== 'Carl';
```